# Передача значения из javascript в form.action в jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, jade, pug, атрибуты

У меня есть тег `form` в jade, из NodeJs в jade я передаю строку `path`, мне нужно сделать, чтобы `action` у формы был равен соединенным `"/first/second/"` и этой строке (Если `path==='custom'`, то `action==='/first/second/custom'`), раньше делал так `div!= '<input value="'+#{myValue}+'"/>'`, но теперь мне надо передать значение в форму и у формы есть дочерние элементы, можно конечно сделать тег `script` и этим скриптом менять значение, но это не самый лучший вариант.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему вы используя возможности jade собираете html-разметку вручную `'<input value="'+#{myValue}+'"/>'`

Comment: @Lemix изначально пробовал соединять строку и переменную js, из-за чего везде и писал так, теперь изменю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так. Создали тег `form` в скобках задали необходимые атрибуты, а уровнем ниже по дереву создали любые вложенные элементы (в моём примере `input`):

```
 div   
     form(action=path)
          input(value=myValue)
```

Это выдаст следующий html-код:

```
<div>  
     <form action="<значение переменной path>">
          <input value="<значение переменной myValue>"/>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Сначала я не уточнил в вопросе, что проблема была в соединении моего текста и значения переменной. Теперь делаю так: `- var path1="/first/second/"+path` и потом `form(action=path1)`

Comment: @Александр Объединить можно и в атрибуте `form(action='/first/second/' + path)`

Comment: Странно, у меня из-за этого и возникла проблема, я пытался так написать, но в итоге выдало ошибку...

Comment: Проверил, всё прекрасно работает. Конечно, может быть из-за того, что я обновил jade на pug